# C++: “invalid comparator” assert

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Here is the code:

```
struct Payment
{
    Payment(time_t time, float money) : mTime(time), mMoney(money) {}
    bool operator==(const Payment& p) const // exact comparison
    {
        return mTime == p.mTime && mMoney == p.mMoney;
    }
    time_t  mTime;
    float   mMoney;
};

std::vector<Payment>    payments;

auto sortP = [](const Payment& p1, const Payment& p2) { return p1.mTime < p2.mTime || p1.mMoney <= p2.mMoney; };
std::sort(payments.begin(), payments.end(), sortP);
```

`std::sort` (not always, but sometimes, when `mTime` of two elements close to each other) raises invalid comparator assert in Visual Studio 2015. What's wrong with the code?
 [image]

Comment: `|| p1.mMoney <= p2.mMoney` should be `|| ((p1.mTime == p2.mTime) && (p1.mMoney < p2.mMoney))` Otherwise comparison will be wrong for case when `p1.mTime` is greater than `p2.mTime` while `p1.mMoney` is less than `p2.Money`.

Comment: Comparing two floats is not a good idea, floats are not represented exactly, they are approximations. You need to compare that the difference is less than some delta. by the same reasoning putting money in a float is not a good idea.

Comment: @VTT: You are right, this is the solution. Make it an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: In general you cannot use `<=` for strict weak ordering, as it requires false for equal elements.

Comment: @AndersK. in this case delta is not required, unless OP uses that criteria to find element. For actual sorting it can make it slower.

Comment: @Slava It's not just speed. Comparison with delta is not a valid strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Slava  mMoney == p.mMoney will not work

Comment: @AndersK. first of all it will work, maybe not the way somebody would expect it, second strict weak ordering, which is used by `std::sort()` does not use `==`

Comment: @Stava it is an error to compare floats with each other since floats are not exactly represented, my comment is directed to his comparison function, not whether it fits in this particular fringe case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|| p1.mMoney <= p2.mMoney` should be `|| ((p1.mTime == p2.mTime) && (p1.mMoney < p2.mMoney))` Otherwise comparison will be wrong for case when `p1.mTime` is greater than `p2.mTime` while `p1.mMoney` is less than `p2.Money`. A good practice to ensure that such multi-field comparator satisfy strict weak ordering requirement is to write tests for all possible lt/gt combinations of fields.

Comment: Good practice is to use `std::tie`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the implementation of `sortP`. It does not satisfy the strictly weak ordering criteria. Read the details at https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html.

I suggest the following change:

```
auto sortP = [](const Payment& p1, const Payment& p2)
{
   // Order by mTime if they are not equal.
   if ( p1.mTime != p2.mTime)
   {
     return p1.mTime < p2.mTime;
   }

   // Otherwise, order by pMoney
   return ( p1.mMoney < p2.mMoney); // Use < not <=
};
```

You can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to make the implementation simpler.

```
auto sortP = [](const Payment& p1, const Payment& p2)
{
   return std::tie(p1.mTime, p1.mMoney) < std::tie(p2.mTime, p2.mMoney);
};
```

Comment: Using `std::tie` is simpler

Comment: @Slava, of course. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The link in your answer is broken.

Comment: @CourageousPotato, Thanks for pointing out the broken link. Removed the old link and added a new link.

Answer (score 1):

Using `c++11` your comparator lambda should look like:

```
#include <tuple>
...
auto sortP = [](const Payment& p1, const Payment& p2) 
{ 
     return std::tie(p1.mTime, p1.mMoney) < std::tie(p2.mTime, p2.mMoney);
};
```